# How To Set Under Line In Jsf Tags. i want to set under line on one character

Tags: jsf

I want to set underline only one character on command button and commandLink . 
Example in html :

```
<button type="button"><u>C</u>lick Me!</button>
```

how it is possible on jsf command button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how for commandLink

```
<h:commandLink style="text-decoration:none;"> 
    <h:outputText value="&lt;u&gt;C&lt;/u&gt;lick Me!" escape="false"/> 
</h:commandLink>
```

Not sure how it can be done for commandButton with JSF only... You might want to try changing the value with jquery...